# Python - Convert string to array/rows

Tags: python

I'm doing a test in Python3 trying to convert a string from `http.client` to a array/row format.

```
val1 = "error"
val2 = "message"
array = (val1,val2)
value = "('error', 'message')"
print(value[1])
 >> error
print(array[1])
 >> '
```

I would like to get what I get when I run `print(value[1])` using a string.
Thanks :)

Comment: Also, `(val1, val2)` is a tuple, not an array, just to be clear.

Comment: @danielhadar: No, that's a list, not an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

Comment: Show **clearly** the expected result for what you want. Else answers will come from a  second-guessed notion of your original intention

Comment: It's hard to tell what your asking (and the output of your code sample looks a bit mixed up). Are you trying to extract sub-strings like `'error'` and `'message'` from a string that looks like `"('error', 'message')"`?

Comment: Are you talking about key-value string pairs? If yes, dictionaries would be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
val1 = "error"
val2 = "message"
myValues = (val1,val2)
print(myValues[1])
 >> message
```

Works here

- `(val1,val2)` is a tuple
- `[val1,val2]` is an list
- `{'error': 4098, 'message': 'My message'}` is a dictionary

Comment: @DanielRoseman correct, changed it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you wish to do, but I think it's this.

```
val1 = "error"
val2 = "message"
array = [val1, val2]
print(array[0])  # this will print "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a string into a tuple you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
 import ast
 value = "('error', 'message')"
 ast.literal_eval(value) # = ('error','message')
```

Not clear what you really want to do?